# I can't get the invoices where invoiceTotalAmount is greater than 0

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have an error when i execute the request below trying to get the invoices where invoiceTotalAmount is greater than 0 :
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices.json?objectFilter={"invoices":{"invoiceTotalAmount":{"operation":">0"}}}&resultLimit=0,100&objectMask=mask[id,createDate,typeCode,invoiceTotalAmount]

Answer (score 0):

That is an bug, I recommend you to report the bug to softlayer by submitting and ticket.